# NodeJS Proactive Messaging in Bot-framework for Skill Bot

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am working on a requirement in NodeJS where I have to invoke proactive messages from Skill Bot. I have a set Interval loop which runs for every 8 seconds where I added adapter.ContinueConversation method. I have added the below code in skill bot on message method initially but I received 401 Unauthorized error.

```
await context.sendActivity(`Echo (JS) : '${ context.activity.text }'`);
await context.sendActivity('Say "end" or "stop" and I\'ll end the conversation and back to the parent.');
var adapter = context.adapter;
var conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
var refreshInterval = setInterval(async () => {
try {
     await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity('Are you still there?');
    });
} 
catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
}
}, 8000,conversationReference);
```

After doing some research online, i have added additional parameters like claims identity and Root Bot's App Id as below but now I receive error that **adapter.continueConversationAsync is not a function**

```
var conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(stepContext.context.activity);
var claimsIdentity= stepContext.context.turnState.get(stepContext.context.adapter.BotIdentityKey);    
var oAuthScope= stepContext.context.turnState.get(stepContext.context.adapter.OAuthScopeKey);

await adapter.continueConversationAsync(claimsIdentity, convRef, oAuthScope, async context => {    
      await context.sendActivity("hello");
  })
```

Can anyone please help resolve the issue?

Comment: Need some more information to find the solution. Kindly edit the question and add few more inputs like screenshots of error and workflow followed.

Comment: SairamTadepalli-MT I updated the question, could you please help now

Answer (score 2):

First, you're receiving the error, "adapter.continueConversationAsync is not a function" because your parameters are wrong. Per the docs there are two overloaded versions of the continueConversation method :

```
function continueConversation(reference: Partial<ConversationReference>, logic: (context: TurnContext) => Promise<void>): Promise<void>
```

and

```
function continueConversation(reference: Partial<ConversationReference>, oAuthScope: string, logic: (context: TurnContext) => Promise<void>): Promise<void>
```

Your initial implementation was fine, the problem isn't the lack of oAuthScope. I can think of three possible reasons why you get a 401 error :

1. Your appID and appPassword for your bot adapter might not be set correctly.
   Verify your appId and appPassword is correct.

   ```
    const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
        appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
        appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
    });
   ```
2. Try trusting the service URL of the conversation reference :

   ```
    var conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(stepContext.context.activity);

    await adapter.continueConversationAsync(conversationReference, async context => {    
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(conversationReference.serviceUrl);
        await context.sendActivity("hello");
    })
   ```

And finally, try logging your conversationReference and verify the conversationReference itself is correct. Although since you're getting the conversationReference from the turncontext right before sending the proactive message this part shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I tried adding app Id password as per your suggestion for adapter but I got the same unauthorized error

Comment: Did you also try trusting the serviceURL of the conversation reference as per my example?